# Doctrine Entity Design for a simple key-value-group table

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, database-design, doctrine

I have a data table like this:

```
id|name|group
```

That hold simple hierarchical data, for list reference. For exemple I can have on this table a list of countries or cities or a list of product types.

and in a product table with that structure:

```
id|name|city|country|type
```

and in each column (city|country|type) an ID (key) of the row in the data table.

I am starting using Symfony2 and I don't know how to represent this kind of data in Doctrine Entity. I dont want to have an entity for each group of data in the data table...

Thank you

Comment: Think the other way: which objects do I want to use in PHP, after that you add mapping details

Comment: I need this data only for views or for search (by ID). So I dont need object for this

Comment: The ORM only works with objects, data stored in the database is represented by objects in php

Comment: yes so my question is what can I do in my case, I don't need objects, Mabe one object for all group of data. But How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You could achive just what you want but you **need to write an entity**.

1. Write an entity class
2. Create custom `EntityRepository` (maybe, if you'd like to separate queries from controller)
3. Query the database with query like this:

   ```
   $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
   $em->createQuery('SELECT e FROM MyNamespace:Entity e INDEX BY e.key')
   ->getArrayResult();` // INDEX keyword is crucial here
   ```
4. You get the `key => value` structure as an output.

I know, it a bit overkill...

### UPDATE

Ok, I scratched a bit of code just to show you an example: http://codepad.org/f2pzjnrd

Comment: I am a beginner on Doctrine. Could you please give more details on your answer ?

Comment: Thank you. But I didn't understand how this is help me. :) How can I do a reliationship between, for example, the city field on my product entity, and the list of cities on my data entity (as you described it)  and also relationship between type field on product and group of types on data entity?

Comment: Weeel, I think that cannot be achieved :) You need to do in your `Twig`: `all_my_cities[product.city]`. Another option would be extending `Twig` with custom filter but that is a bit advanced topic...